# How to create tabs with an active class in React using functional components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make the Header component in my app show which page is being rendered by adding an "active" class to it when the user clicks on it. This seems like a useState hook problem, but I can't seem to get the conditional operator to change the class name.

Here is my Header.js file:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import '../css/Header.css';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Header() {
    const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState("homeHeaderLink");

    function handleClick(event){
        const clickedId = event.target.id;
        console.log(clickedId);
        setActiveId(clickedId);
    }

    return <div className="topnav">
        <Link
            to={'/profile'}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <AccountCircleIcon
                fontSize={"large"}
                index={"profileHeaderLink"}
                className={`profile-icon ${activeId === "profileHeaderLink" ? 'active' : ''}`}
            />
        </Link>
        <Link
            to={'/'}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <span
                id={"homeHeaderLink"}
                className={activeId === "homeHeaderLink" ? 'active' : ''}
            >Home</span>
        </Link>
        <Link
            to={'/ballot'}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <span
                id={"ballotHeaderLink"}
                className={activeId === "ballotHeaderLink" ? 'active' : ''}
            >Ballot</span>
        </Link>
        <Link
            to={'/dates'}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <span
                id={"datesHeaderLink"}
                className={activeId === "datesHeaderLink" ? 'active' : ''}
            >Dates</span>
        </Link>
    </div>
}

export default Header;
```

The "active" class simply changes the `color` property to green, and it works when I hard code it into the class name of the elements.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: which version of `react-router-dom` are you using? And also it'll be much helpful if you create a [sandbox] (https://codesandbox.io/) of this issue with relevant minimal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`<NavLink>` component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) instead of `<Link>` and it will automatically add a class when the route is matched, along with providing several customization options.

Comment: Thanks @Riley, this makes things much easier. Turns out I had a more specific selector in my CSS, and then the spans inside of the NavLinks were also preventing the style from being applied to the text.